# How to run the application from the other system

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, configuration, app-config

Application is running in my local system

app.config file

```
<add key="dbconn" value="Data Source=(local);database=VTech;User ID=sa;Password=sa;" />
    <add key="rpPath" value="C:\ATech\Reports\" />
    <add key="dbUid" value="sa" />
    <add key="dbPwd" value="sa" />
    <add key="dbSvr" value="ATech" />
<add key="dbName" value="VTech" />
```

The above configuraton is running my local system, now i want to install the application in other 
system, then i want to configure sql server and report configuration to my system

my computer name is `accsystem`
ip address is `10.1.1.190`

I tried like this, but showing error, while running the application in other system

```
<add key="dbconn" value="Data Source=\\10.1.1.190\;database=VTech;User ID=sa;Password=sa;" />
    <add key="rpPath" value="\\10.1.1.190\C:\ATech\Reports\" />
    <add key="dbUid" value="sa" />
    <add key="dbPwd" value="sa" />
    <add key="dbSvr" value="ATech" />
<add key="dbName" value="VTech" />
```

I shared and full access to my application folder, but still it is showing error.

What wrong in my code.

Need Code Help

Comment: \\10.1.1.190\C:\ATech\Reports\ is not a valid path

Comment: If you share your folder, than path should be like this "\\accsystem\Reports\", and DataSource in dbconn would be better just 'accsystem' or what is your server name is

Comment: Do you use SqlServer Express with a named instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<add key="dbconn" value="Data Source=10.1.1.190;database=VTech;User ID=sa;Password=sa;" />
<add key="rpPath" value="\\10.1.1.190\Reports\" />
<add key="dbUid" value="sa" />
<add key="dbPwd" value="sa" />
<add key="dbSvr" value="ATech" />
```

Hope this help

Comment: So you are sure OP has a share `Reports`

Comment: If windows authentication means, how i want to change my connection string...?